# Examples of Dedkind Domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I want to figure out if the ring

$$R=\frac{k[x,y]}{((x^2+y^2)^2+xy)}$$
is a Dedekind Domain or not?

Certainly this is Noetherian, since $k[x,y]$ is Noetherian. Figuring out whether the ideal is prime or not is difficult.
Also I am not sure how to conclude if it is Integrally closed.

Or can I use one of the equivalent statments for Dedekind Domains. That is $A$ is Dedekind Domain, if the localisations around prime ideals are discrete valuation rings.

Comment: how is $xy$ in this ideal?

Comment: oh jeez, I read the plus as a comma. My apologies!

Comment: $R$ is noetherian, an integral domain and every nonzero prime ideal is maximal, but it is not integrally closed.

Comment: How? Which element in the frac field is integral but isn't in $R$. Any general idea or trial and error? @Don

Comment: Can you show that the localization at the maximal ideal $(x,y)$ is not a dvr by showing the maximal ideal is not principal?

Comment: The origin is a singularity for the curve (probably related to what Mohan had in mind). The real locus is a rotated lemniscate.

Comment: @Mohan, Right. But how did you figure out immediately? i want to know what if I get some other quotient ring. What should I localise at in that case?

Comment: If $A=k[x,y]/((x^2+y^2)^2+xy)$ was a Dedekind domain then $B=A_{(x,y)}$ would be a DVR so that $B/(x,y)^2=B/(\pi^2)$ would be (as ring) of the form $L+\pi L$ with $L\cong B/(\pi)$ which is $\cong k$. As $B/(x,y)^2\cong k[x,y]/(x^2,y^2,xy)$ you know that $A$ is not a Dedekind domain, whence not integrally closed.

Comment: Well, the only explanation I have is that I have been doing this sort of thing for fifty years.